# Proving $\Theta(n^{k})= {n \choose k}$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I need help proving  $n\choose k$$=\Theta(n^{k})$ where $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$

if $0<\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}\le\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}<\infty$

Can someone show me the calculation?

Comment: Hint:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\binom{n}k}{n^k}=\frac1{k!}$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\to 1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}= \frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}
$$

Notice that the right hand side has $k$ terms in the numerator, and each of those is less than $n$. So
$$
{n\choose k}\leq \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$

Therefore we have $\limsup_{n\to\infty}{n\choose k}/n^k\leq \frac{1}{k!}$.

For the other side we need a lower bound.

In the first equation each term in the numerator on the right hand side is at least $n-k+1$. So

$$
{n\choose k}\geq \frac{(n-k+1)^k}{k!}
$$

Therefore we have
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}{n\choose k}/n^k\geq \frac{1}{k!}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-k+1)^k}{n^k}.
$$

But actually the $\liminf$ on the right is a well-defined limit:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n-k+1)^k}{n^k}=1.
$$

This can be seen using L'Hopital's Rule for example.

Putting everything together:

$$
\frac{1}{k!}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}{n\choose k}/n^k\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}{n\choose k}/n^k\leq \frac{1}{k!}.
$$

So actually:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\choose k}/n^k=\frac{1}{k!}
$$

But the